# python dict.fromkeys() returns empty

Tags: python, dictionary, fromkeys

I wrote the following function. It returns an empty dictionary when it should not. The code works on the command line without function. However I cannot see what is wrong with the function, so I have to appeal to your collective intelligence.

```
def enter_users_into_dict(userlist):
    newusr = {}
    newusr.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
    return newusr

ul = ['john', 'mabel']
nd = enter_users_into_dict(ul)
print nd
```

It returns an empty dict {} where I would expect {'john': 0, 'mabel': 0}.

It is probably very simply but I don't see the solution.

Comment: If you like an answer, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. It gives the responder reputation points and lets everyone else know you aren't looking for a better answer.

Answer (score 10):

fromkeys is a class method, meaning

```
newusr.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
```

is exactly the same as calling

```
dict.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
```

Both which *return* a dictionary of the keys in userlist. You need to assign it to something. Try this instead.

```
newusr = dict.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
return newusr
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really quick. Classes and instantiation seem still a bit alien for me.

Comment: @slooow: You should accept this answer if it helped you (tick the green check mark beside the question).

Answer (score 3):

You need to collapse the function's body to

```
def enter_users_into_dict(userlist):
    return dict.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
```

`fromkeys` is a class method, thus doesn't affect any instance it may be called on (it's best to call it on the class -- that's clearer!), rather it **returns** the new dictionary it builds... and that's exactly the very dictionary you want to return, to!-)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
def enter_users_into_dict(userlist):
    return dict.fromkeys(userlist, 0)
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> `fromkeys()`  is a **class method** that **returns** a new dictionary.